# How do I diagnose and fix a toilet blockage

Tags: plumbing, toilet, septic, blockage

I have a toilet that makes a gurgling noise **IF** it flushes down. However, at times it will fill up when I flush the toilet and I will see something come up from the bathroom drain. I have tried putting septic tank cleanser through the toilet because I have a septic tank.

What should I do to find and fix the problem?

Comment: Try searching for blocked toilet in this forum and then if you have a more specific question that arises update your question with more info

Comment: Is it just the one toilet that is a problem, or do other fixtures not drain properly either?

Comment: sounds like the vent is blocked

Comment: If the drain is backing up as well, the problem is surely downstream of both fixtures.  This is not a toilet problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a blockage that is in the main pipe downstream of where toilet and the bathroom drain collect, so it is backing up both of them. Since the chemicals are not doing it, it looks like it has to be augered.